# Открытие новой сцены в потоке Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, progress-bar

есть код который запускает другой код и отображает в progressbar уровень выполнения этих кодов.
это происходит в `void initialize(){...}`

```
 void initialize() throws IOException {
     new Thread(() -> {
         try {
             map_8_8.SetZero();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         Platform.runLater(() -> bar.setProgress( bar.getProgress() + 0.33 ));
         try {
             map_8_8.Bomb();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         Platform.runLater(() -> bar.setProgress( bar.getProgress() + 0.33 ));
         try {
             map_8_8.GetBoxValue();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         Platform.runLater(() -> bar.setProgress(1));
     }).start();
```

и после заполнения Progressbar должа быть заргузка другой сцены, можно подставить её например в последний пункт:

```
    @FXML
    void initialize() throws IOException {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                map_8_8.SetZero();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Platform.runLater(() -> bar.setProgress( bar.getProgress() + 0.33 ));
            try {
                map_8_8.Bomb();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Platform.runLater(() -> bar.setProgress( bar.getProgress() + 0.33 ));
            try {
                map_8_8.GetBoxValue(); // запуск кода после выполнения последнего которого я запускаю другую сцену
                try {
                    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("8X8.fxml")));
                    Stage window = (Stage) bar.getScene().getWindow();
                    window.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Platform.runLater(() -> bar.setProgress(1));
        }).start();
      
    }
```

но вылетает ошибка:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-3
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:292)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:446)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Stage.setScene(Stage.java:265)
    at com.example.javasapp/com.example.javasapp.load_8_8.lambda$initialize$3(load_8_8.java:48)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

как можно это исправить или добиться желаемого результата без этой ошибки?

Comment: Ну очевидно что поток пытается что-то изменить в графике, влезая в чужой поток. Постарайтесь сделать больше обёрток в runLater(() или создать отдельный класс Task. Для прогресс бара, лучше использовать зависимость.

Comment: Хммм, спасибо, я вас понял, можно примерный код Task. Для прогресс бара

Comment: Сейчас сделаем )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полная версия тут https://github.com/Platence/TaskProgressBar/tree/main/src/sample
Пример с использованием класса Task

```
 public class ProcessingBar extends Task<Void> {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private static final double MAX_VALUE = 1.0D;

    public ProcessingBar(ProgressBar progressBar) {
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {

        // Есть ещё вариант с методом bind
        // Например
        // progressBar.progressProperty().bind(this.progressProperty());

        double startValue = 0D;
        System.out.println("start");
        while (startValue<MAX_VALUE){
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            setValue(startValue+=0.1D);
            System.out.println("Change Bar");
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void setValue(double value){
        Platform.runLater(()->{this.progressBar.setProgress(value);});
    }




}
```

Код из контроллера

```
    public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane mainPane;

    public void initialize() {
        ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar();
        pb.setLayoutY(10);
        pb.setLayoutX(10);

        ProgressBar pb2 = new ProgressBar();
        pb2.setLayoutY(30);
        pb2.setLayoutX(30);


        Platform.runLater(() ->
                {
                    mainPane.getChildren().add(pb);
                    mainPane.getChildren().add(pb2);
                }
        );

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ProcessingBar(pb));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ProcessingBar(pb2));
        t1.setDaemon(true);t2.setDaemon(true);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

    }
}
```